# Is there any email app on macos that only lets you send email only? no receiving

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I'm trying to find an application that solves this problem because i have focus issues when my gmail is spammed with 1000+ emails.

Comment: As an alternative, there are some "Inbox Pause" plugins for Gmail which let you pause all incoming mail for certain period. I've used an app called 'Boomerang' in the past to do just this.

Comment: Have you tried setting your Mail server to check for messages *Manually* and not periodically?

Comment: Additionally, what platform/version are you on?  Is this for an iPad/iPhone or a Mac?  There are several tools available to help you like [setting a Focus](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/turn-a-focus-on-or-off-mchl999b7c1a/mac).  What have you attempted?

Comment: I'm using macos ventura